# Web API + Unity - Reference object dbcontext already instantiated

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, unity-container

I'm using Unity for dependency injection.

I have a method responsible to instantiate the Database Object as follow:

```
        container.RegisterType<DB>(
            new InjectionFactory(c =>
            {
                return new DB();
            })
        );
```

The problem is, I have a method that use two different objects that are suposed to be referenced to the same DB instance, but look's like Unity are creating a new instance of DB Object in each injection.

Query LINQ example:

```
var test = from tb1 in _db1.method()
           join tb2 in _db2.method() on tb1.code equals tb2.code
```

_db1 and _db2 reference the same DB Object as follow

```
    DB _db = null;

    public db1(DB dataContext)
    {
        _db = dataContext;
        _db.CommandTimeout = 3600;
    }
```

So i'm getting the following error:

> The query contains references to items defined on a different data context

Could some one help me fix Unity register to reference the DB Object already instantiated instead do a new every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should register your db as a singleton in the container, that means each time the db is requested the same instance is returned, this:

```
container.RegisterType<DB>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager())
```

should do it, if this is a web application you should probably create a child container for each request there are different ways to do this, but you might want to give https://www.nuget.org/packages/Unity.Mvc4/ a try

Comment: Now when i register a dependency i'm using this following code:

`container.RegisterType<IAdminDB, AdminDB>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());`

HierarchicalLifetimeManager() should be replaced to ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()?

Comment: Doing like you said I started to get this error: `An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'ExampleController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."`. I'm without ideas.

Comment: @MarceloBarbosa, do you register the `ExampleController` with the container? Can you show how does the constructor `ExampleController` look like? Can you show how are you using the container to resolve objects? Are you using `IDependencyResolver` or `IHttpControllerActivator`?

Comment: by default unity uses TransientLifetimeManager, so each time a request for an instance is made en new one is created. HierarchicalLifetimeManager and ContainerControlledLifetimeManager only create a single instance of the reqeust type and reuse it. The diffence between the last is relevent when you are using childcontainers. ContainerControlledLifetimeManager will make sure all the child containers use the same instance and with HierarchicalLifetimeManager the instance is unique per child container.

Comment: As for your controller exception I think this is a seperate issue and it looks like you haven't hookup your container correctly with the mvc pipeline and the default mvc resolver doesn't like constructors with arguments.

Comment: I've fixed the problem using this code: `container.RegisterType<DB>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager(), new InjectionFactory(c => { return new DB(); })); Thanks @RobbertDraaisma`